# Specifying variable outside of render in React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    let name=this.props.name;

    render() {
       return (
            <h1>
              {name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);e
```

Hi All,I'm new to React and i'm stuck in a problem,i wanted to display the name through props but its not working, if i use  `name=this.props.name` inside render() it works fine,But how to get its value outside render,Please help out and Thanks in advance

Comment: Please go through react component life cycle.https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Why do  you want to do it like this? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the ES wiki

> There is (intentionally) no direct declarative way to define either
>   prototype data properties (other than methods) class properties, or
>   instance property
>
> Class properties and prototype data properties need be created outside
>   the declaration.
>
> Properties specified in a class definition are assigned the same
>   attributes as if they appeared in an object literal.

a class definition defines prototype methods - defining variables on the prototype is generally not something you do.

To get the value outside of render, you can have a variable in the constructor and then access its value like

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.name = props.name
    }
    render() {
       return (
            <h1>
              {this.name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

With the [`Es7 initializers`](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/es7-property-initializers). you can do

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    name = this.props.name
    render() {
       return (
            <h1>
              {this.name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

However, since you are assigning a value based on the props, the ideal method is to make use of lifecycle functions and then use it. If you want to update in a state, then the better palce is to have this logic in the `componentWillMount` and the `componentWillReceiveProps` fucntion.

However if you only want to update the variable and use it in render, the best place is to have it in the render function itself

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: ''
    }
    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({name:this.props.name});
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({name: this.props.name});
    }
    render() {
       return (
            <h1>
              {this.state.name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

or

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
   
    render() {
       let name = this.props.name
       return (
            <h1>
              {name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: OP isn't *updating* a value based on props, they're *setting* a value based on props. I don't see any indication it's expected to update (and obviously if they are, they'll be sad).

Comment: The final snippet is a repeat of what the OP already knows works. The question is what problem they're trying to solve--without knowing that, providing meaningful advice is difficult.

Comment: @DaveNewton, As I mentioned in the answer, what other person is trying to achieve can be done by using ES7 style or using the constructor. And I agree it is difficult to advice what the OP wants to achive, however I gave him hte possible approaches

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Parent extends React.Component {
    let name=props.name; // no need to use this.props.name
    /* but a better way is to directly use {this.props.name} 
       inside the <h1> tag if you are not manipulating the data.
    */
    render() {
       return (
            <h1>
              {name}
           </h1>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent name="Luffy"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```