# Reactjs classes vs javascript classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, inheritance, prototype

In JavaScript, we are not allowed to use variables and we can only define methods. Also if we want to initialise a variable, we should do it either in the constructor or the prototype of the class.But in ReactJs we can initialise state outside constructor.

Is ReactJs classes like `class A extends React.Component{}` different from normal javascript classes?

Comment: It is class properties syntax, supported by babel and is an ES7 syntax. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048879/specifying-variable-outside-of-render-in-react-class/45048994#45048994

Comment: This article [React.createClass vs. ES6 Class Components](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-create-class-vs-es6-class-components/) gives a really good explanation on the history as well as the differences of the two classes.Thought of extracting a few paragraphs from this article and posting it as an answer but I think a complete read of the article would be better instead.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Except that it didn't make it into ES7, it's still a proposal only :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can refer [Class variables in React with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489792/class-variables-in-react-with-es6)

JS by default does not support declaring variables inside class.
In case of React, it uses Babel transpiler which supports that syntax.